# ibm-eventstreams-dev does not deploy into IBM Cloud Private

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, ibm-eventstreams

I tried to install ibm-eventstreams-dev v 0.1.1 into IBM Cloud Private and i get an error message:

Internal Service Error : Chart Incompatible with Tiller v2.6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Background**

As the error message says, IBM Event Streams requires Helm (Tiller) v2.7.2 or greater. (see https://github.com/IBM/charts/blob/master/stable/ibm-eventstreams-dev/Chart.yaml#L5 )

IBM Cloud Private (ICP) has [come with Helm (Tiller) v2.7.2 out of the box since v 2.1.0.2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0.2/getting_started/components.html) so as long as you're on 2.1.0.2 or 2.1.0.3 there is nothing to worry about.

**Getting it working**

If you're on ICP v2.1.0.1 or earlier, then the best thing to do would be to update to 2.1.0.2 or greater first - as that should be able to install IBM Event Streams.

If you're already on ICP 2.1.0.2+ but the Tiller install has been downgraded to 2.6.0, the easiest thing to do would probably be to restore the Tiller version.

1. Download and configure the v 2.7.2 Helm CLI by following the "[Installing the Helm CLI](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0.2/app_center/create_helm_cli.html)" instructions that come with ICP
2. Run `helm init --upgrade --tls` to upgrade your Tiller install using the ICP version

Answer (score 3):

IBM Event Streams requires as a minimum Helm (Tiller) version 2.7.2.  This version of Tiller ships with IBM Cloud Private (ICP) 2.1.0.2, which is also the minimum required version of ICP for IBM Event Streams to install.

Ensure you're running ICP at 2.1.0.2 or later, and if your Tiller has somehow ended up back level try

```
helm init --upgrade --tiller-image 2.7.2
```

to upgrade back to the default.